# ディレクトリ内の画像のグループ化

Tags: macos, filesystems

私は.jpg画像を含むディレクトリを持っています。これらの画像をファイル名でグループ化するために私の端末から使用できるコマンドはありますか？たとえば、これらの画像を名前でディレクトリに分類する方法があります。
A-1-adriana.jpg
A-2-adriana.jpg
A-1-arabesco.jpg
A-1-anticoconvitto.jpg
A-1-arabesco.jpg
A-1-anticoconvitto.jpg

Comment: 質問のファイルリストの場合に、どのようなグループ化(ファイルの移動？)の結果になることを期待しているかも記載しておくと回答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: 画像のタイトルが入っているディレクトリに、一致する各画像を入れます。

Comment: 意図が伝わっていない気がしますが、正確な条件をつけられますか？例えば、「A-1」「A-2」が共通点として挙げられますが、「adriana」という共通点もあります。グループ化するルールや、アルゴリズムの想定があるなら記載してください。

Comment: 別のフォルダにある名前ごとに、「A-1」、「A-2」、「A-3」、「A-4」、「A-5」が必要です。 1つのフォルダにすべての "adriana"イメージがあります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)からrenameをインストールして、

```
$ brew install rename
```

renameコマンドでリネーム。

```
$ rename -p 's!^([A-Z]-\d+)-(\w+)!$2/$1!i' *.jpg
```

### デモ

```
✔ kojima:skmbp renametest$ tree
.
|-- A-1-adriana.jpg
|-- A-1-anticoconvitto.jpg
|-- A-1-arabesco.jpg
|-- A-2-adriana.jpg
|-- A-2-anticoconvitto.jpg
`-- A-2-arabesco.jpg

0 directories, 6 files
✔ kojima:skmbp renametest$ rename -p 's!^([A-Z]-\d+)-(\w+)!$2/$1!i' *.jpg
✔ kojima:skmbp renametest$ tree
.
|-- adriana
|   |-- A-1.jpg
|   `-- A-2.jpg
|-- anticoconvitto
|   |-- A-1.jpg
|   `-- A-2.jpg
`-- arabesco
    |-- A-1.jpg
    `-- A-2.jpg

3 directories, 6 files
```

Comment: 画像を含むディレクトリからこれを実行しますか？

Comment: 私たちはチャットをすることができますか、あなたは私にあなたにディレクトリを見せますか？

Comment: @CodyRutscher ええ、カレントディレクトリに画像が存在する想定です。ディレクトリ構成と期待するツリーの詳細を教えてくれればいいのですが。